# Why PageSpeed Insights reduce my calification when adding google advertisement in my website?

Tags: adsense, pagespeed

Why PageSpeed Insights reduce my calification when adding google advertisement in my website ?

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=es&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftaptapking.com%2F

Is there any way to optimize the code load? try asynchronously and loading ad units from js.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Your PageSpeed score will always be lowered when you have AdSense or other ad networks actively running on your site.

All AdSense is already loading asynchronously. You can only have a marginal affect on the ad loading speed by deciding at what point during the page loading process you want to trigger the loading of your AdSense code.

Even extremely well optimized websites will generally not get a PageSpeed score of 100/100 if their pages have AdSense code on it.

Google Page Speed only gives you basic insight into what could be improved. Try checking your site on webpagetest.org instead to better test your site's Loading Speed.